# Stop Custom animation effect when change the Orientation in Android

Tags: android, animation, orientation

Here i develop one android application,in application i given frame animation with animation-list drawable xml file on ImageView, it working nice but when i change the orientation animation stop to working.

please help me,
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

i got the answer of my question

only write in AndroidManifest file in particular activity tag